# Swift Adding objects from on array to another array correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsmutablearray

So I have 2 NSMutableArrays, one called testArray and the other called jsonArray. jsonArray gets its objects from a mysql server using json and php. Then those same objects in jsonArray are inserted in testArray. I did print(jsonArray, testArray) and what showed in the logs were this.

I also have a NSObject class called Test, if that helps..

For the jsonArray

```
 {
  testName = GreenCorn;
  testStatus1 = 12;
  testStatus2 = 13;
  testURL = "";
  id = 1;
 }
```

For the testArray

```
"<CustomCellSwift.Test: 0x17414df70>"
```

Now I'm new to iOS Swift but I don't know if I inserted the jsonArray into testArray correctly. Here is the code I used. Also, I'm using a custom tableview and its supposed to show testArray.count, its empty cells but its showing the several rows that I have in jsonArray.

```
var followedArray: NSMutableArray = []
var testArray: NSMutableArray = []

var jsonArray: NSMutableArray = []
var filteredArray: NSArray = []

var isFiltered: Bool = false


// Number of Rows in Section
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if !isFiltered {
        if section == 0 {
            return followedArray.count
        }
        else if section == 1 {
            return testArray.count
        }
    }
    return filteredArray.count

}


internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier) as! CustomCell

    if cell != cell {
        cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }

    // Coloring TableView
    myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    // Configuring the cell
    var testObject: Test

    print("before ifFiltered")

    if !isFiltered {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            print("isFiltered if")
            testObject = followedArray[indexPath.row] as! Test
            cell.populateCell(testObject, isFollowed: true, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            print("isFiltered if 2")
            testObject = testArray[indexPath.row] as! Test
            cell.populateCell(testObject, isFollowed: false, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
        }
    }
    else {
        print("isFiltered else")
        testObject = filteredArray[indexPath.row] as! Test
        cell.populateCell(testObject, isFollowed: false, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
    }

    return cell
}





// Retrieving Data from Server
func retrieveData() {

    let getDataURL = "http://exampleip.org/json.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {

        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

        // Setting up testArray
        let testArray: NSMutableArray = []

        // Looping through jsonArray
        for i in 0..<jsonArray.count {

            // Create Test Object
            let tID: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "id") as! String
            let tName: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "testName") as! String
            let tStatus1: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "testStatus1") as! String
            let tStatus2: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "testStatus2") as! String
            let tURL: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "testURL") as! String

            // Add Test Objects to Test Array
            testArray.add(Test(testName: tName, andTestStatus1: tStatus1, andTestStatus2: tStatus2, andTestURL: tURL, andTestID: tID))

            print("retrieveData")
            print(jsonArray, testArray)
        }

    }
    catch {
        print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
    }

    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Am I doing this correctly? Why does my tableview have empty cells?

Comment: You need to show more code. Why is testArray local?

Comment: Not sure from your question, but what's not working ? If the only concern is the empty cells in the tableview, could you also provide the code that fills the cells ? (in the table's data source)

Comment: @johnelemans I updated my code

Comment: @bogdanf I updated the code on top, yeah the cells are coming back empty but it shows 12 rows that the array should have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing this line of code worked.

```
let testArray: NSMutableArray = []
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your networking/serialization code shouldn't be in your ViewController, but this is a better way to do things:

```
func retrieveData() {

    let getDataURL = "http://exampleip.org/json.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {

        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        guard let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String : AnyObject]] else {
            print("Error Retrieving Data")
            return
        }

        let testArray = jsonArray.flatMap(Test.init)

        // make sure the add the result in your viewController
        self.myTableView.models = testArray
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
    }

    myTableView.reloadData()
}

extension Test {

    convenience init?(with jsonDictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
        guard let tID = jsonDictionary["id"] as? String, let tName = jsonDictionary["testName"] as? String, let tStatus1 = jsonDictionary["testStatus1"] as? String, 
              let tStatus2 = jsonDictionary["testStatus2"] as? String, let tURL = jsonDictionary["testURL"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        self(testName: tName, andTestStatus1: tStatus1, andTestStatus2: tStatus2, andTestURL: tURL, andTestID: tID)
    }
}
```

I couldn't really test it so there may be some errors, but that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: The extension adds a fallible initializer using a JSON dictionary, and you can learn about map here: https://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/

Comment: I'll try it out asap

Comment: Okay so i got 2 errors, "let testArray = jsonArray.flatMap(Test.init)", saids "Cannot convert value of type Test to expected argument type '([String : AnyObject])' throws -> _" and the second error said "Declaration is only valid at file scope" at the line "extension Test {". - Never seen these errors

Comment: The extension needs to be outside if your class

Comment: Sorry i was at work, now still 2 errors, First Error is in self.myTableView.models = gameArray . What am I supposed to put instead of .models?

Comment: Whatever variable you're using to store the data

Comment: okay sorry but I don't know which data to use, whenever I try any of the var containing the arrays nothing comes up